# Auto fit navtab width in bootstrap 4 after resizing browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

As I'm new to font-end, as a using bootstrap 4 with angular 6. I have navtabs inside my col grid :

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Menu 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

[Image for the Above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6KtC.png)

I just want that Menus tab's width fits automatically inside bootstrap column when screen size changes. Could you guys help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you please share your CSS too. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulBasit css:

 `ul.nav>li>a {
        width: auto !important;
        height: 55px;
        font-size: 17px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 72px;
        padding-top: 13px;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change how much space you want the column to take, you have to adjust each column class depending on your window size. It looks like you’re on a extra small device, so you should add a xs column. And configure with size 12 as that is 100% of the space.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```